# Sqoop import of wide table

Tags: oracle, sqoop

Sqoop import of wide tables from oracle is taking lot of time

The table has more than 300 columns and around 70 million rows. Performance tuning options tried:

```
num mappers 15
fetch size 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with large tables like you described means modify some extra parameters  like map and reduce memory and java max heap. I've shared some configurations for tables not too big but it optimize us the time of processing.

```
import -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -Dmapreduce.job.heap.memory-mb.ratio=0.8 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap=3355443200 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3g
```

PD: I use Sqoop 1 and also recommend to check [Sqoop Documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html) for more details about those parameters.